# A problem about combination with inclusion exclusion principle

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

There are 5 groups, let's say group A, B, C, D E. In each group, you can pick several numbers from 0 to 9. With these 5 groups, we can pick 1 number from each group, and come up to 1 sequence. The order must be ABCDE, and the number can not be duplicated. For example, 12345 is OK, but 11345 is not OK. How many combination of the sequence can you get?

For example:

A := {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9}

B := {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}

C := {1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}

D := {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

E := {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

ABCDE

12345 is Good.

12141 is Bad.

@David Reed

Ya, that is a pain. I use inclusion-exclusion principle, but the answer is wrong.

AB mean the exclusive set of A and B

C(A, 1) * C(B, 1) * C(C, 1) * C(D, 1) * C(E, 1)

- C(AB, 1) * C(C, 1) * C(D, 1) * C(E, 1)

- C(AC, 1) * C(B, 1) * C(D, 1) * C(E, 1)

- ... (10 combination in total)

+ C(ABC, 1) * C(D, 1) * C(E, 1)

+ ... (10 combination in total)

- C(ABCD, 1) * C(E, 1)

- ... (5 combinations in total)

+ C(ABCDE, 1)

If we pick all numbers for each groups, (every group has 10 numbers),

A = B = C = D = E = {0 ... 9}

The total combinations is 30240.

With my equation, I can not come up this answer. I think I miss the coefficients, and I don't what coefficients they are. Or, my equation is just completely wrong...

Comment: What is $N$? A constant or a parameter?

Comment: @ThePirateBay I've updated my question. Thank for the comment.

Comment: So, when you said "For example: A:= ..... E:=" are those the numbers that are allowed to be chosen in general? The words "for example" are throwing me off. That is, your choices for B are always {2,3,4,5,6,7}?

Comment: @DavidReed That means
for example, for group B, I pick 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.

Comment: Please make sure choices for the sets are correct. I'm getting 14,112 total sequences possible with repetition allowed. I don't see how it could be higher than this when repetitions are excluded.

Answer (score 0):

Let me preface by saying there's probably a more efficient way to do this.When using the inclusion-

exclusion principle one has to figure out what the "forbidden conditions" are.

Let $A_i$ be the set of all sequences containing more than one $i$

For example $A_3$ would be the set of all sequences containing more than one $3$

The total # of possible sequences is $8*7^2*6^2$ by the rule of product.

For $A_1$, $1$ is an available option in groups A,C, and E. So elements of $A_1$

have the form

$$
\begin{align}
1*1*1 \quad - \ &  6*6  \text{ options}\\
1***1 \quad - \ & 6*7*6 \text{ options}\\
**1*1 \quad - \ & 7*6*6 \text{ options}\\
1*1** \quad - \ & 6 * 6 * 8 \text{ options}
\end{align}
$$

$ \\ $

For $A_2$, $2$ is available in groups A,B,E. Possible types are:

$$
\begin{align}
22**2 \quad -& \ 7*6   \text{ options}\\
2***2 \quad -& \  6*7*6 \text{ options}\\
22*** \quad -& \  7*6*8 \text{ options}\\
*2**2 \quad -&  \ 7*7*6 \text{ options}
\end{align}
$$

Although its a pain, continuing in this way and applying the inclusion-exclusion principle should give you the right result.

Comment: I updated my post.

Comment: @WayneHuang is 30240 the correct answer or the answer you got?

Comment: The correct answer! I wrote a program recursively list all combinations, and I got that answer. My friend got the same answer.

Comment: @WayneHuang For B can you choose any number from 1-9 or only 2,3,4,5,6,7

Comment: @WayneHuang Is that the answer in the book or that's what you got in your program?

Comment: that is my program. I know it could be wrong. But, this is a game. I reference another game apps. They show the same answer. That's why I think 30240 is correct.